# How to tab a window to another via command line?

Tags: command-line, kde, window, scripts, tabs

I have a program that opens a number of windows, which I want to attach as tabs to a main window. The program doesn't understand the KDE window tabs concept, so I would like to tab the windows together at program start and untab them into separate windows before I shut it down.
I do this manually by clicking a window's top left corner, selecting 'attach as tab to...' & selecting a window to attach to. But scripting it would be much nicer, and scripting mouse moves isn't really an answer.

I've looked at KDE's PlasmaDesktopScripting & made a little headway with the Desktop Shell Scripting Console but what I really need from them is a list of the available actions to sift through.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't use KDE, so I can't test, but have a look into `wmctrl` or `xdotool`: they both let you automate X-related events such as keystrokes and mouse clicks. Used rightfully (it might be not *too* straightforward) you should be able to "macro" the routine you usually go through in the GUI into a `bash` script.